# How to avoid flashing button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing a program using WPF(c#). I use several buttons. Anny button start flashing after clicking on it! Its color fading from background color to aqua (light blue) color. It does not stop flashing while I click another button( then this button starts flashing!!!). Is it a bug? is it related to my visual studio?

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Its the defualt VisualStyle of the button, Windows has been using this for years, its not new, it happens when the button has focus, if you want to stop the button from doing it you can override the button template or simply unfocus the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you could try setting the button `Focusable` to `False`. However, this will be a problem if you use keyboard navigation. I did however find this `Window.Resource` XAML code:

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
<Style x:Key="BoringButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then whenever you want to apply the custom button style, set the button `Style` to:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource BoringButtonStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome giving error message. It is Micorsoft.Windows.Themes:ButtonChrome. Its not working. It gives me message that ButtonChrome is not supported in WPF project.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `Button` template to remove the default `Themed(Aero)` style

Something like this will be a good place to start.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" Background="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}" BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrush}">
                    <ContentPresenter  Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#AAAAAA" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```